# How to get timezone in 3 letters using momentjs?

Tags: javascript, timezone, momentjs, timezone-offset

I am getting timezones using following code using moment library

```
console.log(moment.tz.names())
```

Which gives me result in following format

```
0: "Africa/Abidjan"
1: "Africa/Accra"
2: "Africa/Addis_Ababa"
3: "Africa/Algiers"
4: "Africa/Asmara"
5: "Africa/Asmera"
6: "Africa/Bamako"
```

I need to get only abbreviations something like

[image]

Can moment gives such flexibility and also I need to get offsets as well?

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [moment.format(string)](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) to get abbreviation by passing `z` argument:

```
moment.tz(zone).format('z')
```

and offset by passing `Z` argument:

```
moment.tz(zone).format('Z')
```

```js
console.log(
  moment.tz.names().forEach(zone => { 
    console.log( moment.tz(zone).format('Z z') ) 
  }) 
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.25/moment-timezone-with-data.min.js"></script>
```

Please note that the `z` formatting token will not always show the abbreviated time zone name, instead, will show the time offsets for each region and the same thing for `moment#zoneAbbr`.

Comment: I need offsets according to `dst` Is it possible? Because in `dst` one hours gets subtracted/added

Comment: It is DST aware, and will use the correct offset when parsing.

Comment: Hi In the list of above timezones the est - utc difference is `-05:00` when I searched on [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=est+to+utc+time+difference&oq=est+to+ut&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i57j69i60l2.2533j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) it is `-04:00`. Could you please just explain

Comment: `moment.tz('US/Eastern').format('Z')` actually return `-04:00`  and not `-05:00`

Answer (score 5):

You can produce a companion list to the full zone names you get from `moment.tz.names()` by a quick `.map()`:

```
let abbrs = moment.tz.names().map((z) => moment.tz(z).zoneAbbr());
```

For any zone object, `.zoneAbbr()` gives the zone abbreviation.

If you want the offsets, you can instead call `.utcOffset()`:

```
let offsets = moment.tz.names().map((z) => moment.tz(z).utcOffset());
```

Or get both:

```
let zoneInfo = moment.tz.names().map((z) => {
  let zone = moment.tz(z);
  return {
    abbr: zone.zoneAbbr(),
    offset: zone.utcOffset()
  };
});
```

Comment: I am getting following error`(index):33 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'names' of undefined
    at window.onload ((index):33)` Can you pls show me any fiddle?

Comment: @Profer Are you sure you're importing both `moment.js` and `moment-timezone.js`?

Comment: Hmm its working http://jsfiddle.net/godn8u3h/. One more question can I get the offsets as well?

Comment: @Profer yes you can do the same thing but call `.utcOffset()` instead of `.zoneAbbr()`. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Ok thanks a ton . can I get offset in "HH:mm" this is last one

Comment: @Profer I think Moment-timezone keeps the offsets as number (minutes), negative if west of UTC, positive if east.  You could get hours by dividing by 60.